# Web server in a game

Tags: web

I am implementing a 2-player tetris game on the web. One of my colleagues told me that I can implement it or use a web server.

Since this is a game, I think I must implement a server part. What is the point of using a web server in a game development?

Comment: Are you sure your friend didn't mean `Web Service` instead of `web server`?

Comment: Probably you are right. I am not sure what the web service is, by the way.

Comment: `Web Service` is simply a generic, English, term for any software that you utilize remotely by sending requests to an `API`.

Comment: Is it possible to create a peer-to-peer connection between two browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server keeps track of the game while the clients (the 2 people player Tetris) just deal with the UI and User inputs.

**Server**

The server should be in charge of making sure that moves are legal, calculating points, and anything else related to the rules and running of the game. This is where the logic of the game is or where the game is played.

**Client**

This is ONLY used for interacting with the server. There should exists a protocol between the Server and the Client. The client will only send requests to the server, wait for a response and update the UI appropriately. No game logic should be implemented here.

Comment: Then, where is the game logic?

Comment: In the server sorry I should have said that. In the edit I did.

Comment: Should I implement the client and server separately?

Comment: Yes. The server doesn't really need an interface in-fact whenever I implement a server I always use a console application that just waits for the kill command to end the server. The client however is what the user downloads and then connects to the server.

Comment: I see. Then client may be a web page that displays sprites depending on the server's input.

Comment: Exactly. This way the webpage doesn't need to calculate rules and talk to the other webpages just the server.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the server is to talk to each of the clients and bounce data between them. If you need a server for your Tetris game you probably want to have a look into NODE.JS, PHP and WEB sockets.